# Apply Scopes to a Custom Query

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm very new to Sequelize and this may seem like a very noob question.

Is there a way to apply scopes to a custom query either via **Sequelize.Query()** or through a **model.FindAll()** call?

The reason I am attempting to run my own query instead of utilizing the model is lack of CTE or temp table support in order to UNNEST a column.

Alternatively does Sequelize provide any way to create a WHERE clause from an array of scopes?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: not clear, share more details, and you tried code